# Get array from localstorage

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, local-storage

I'm attempting to pull a blacklist array from the options of a chrome extension I'm making. The code to save is working just fine. However when I attempt to load the information I can't get to it.

```
chrome.storage.local.get('value', function (result) {
var BlackList = result.value.split(",");});
```

The the rest of the script can't access the variable BlackList for some reason.

Comment: How accessing a variable is relevant to the local storage? If you replace the 2nd line with `var BlackList = ['just', 'an', 'array'];` - will "the rest of the script" have access to it? PS: it makes sense to use some robust serialization mechanisms (like json) instead of inventing something new.

Comment: You've declared your `BlackList` variable inside your callback function, so it's local _to that function_.

Comment: Looks like the `chrome.storage` api is async, so "the rest of the script" would have to happen after the callback.

Comment: @numbers1311407: even if it was synchronous - it's still another scope.

Comment: Didn't mean to imply that it was not, just meant that defining the variable outside of that scope and calling `get` as written won't solve anything.

Comment: @numbers1311407: I don't see a point in your comment then. ""the rest of the script" would have to happen after the callback" --- it doesn't matter *when* it happens. What matters is that it is *defined in another scope*.

Comment: The point is that the code is written as if it were a one liner to get the value from localstorage.  Likely the "rest of the script" continues after it.